# Linear Maps: $0$ function

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $0$ denote the function ${T}$ that takes each element of some vector space to the additive identity of another vector space. Prove that $T$ is linear.

I just want to make sure I understand the basic properties of a linear map with this very simple function.

$ 0 \in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ defined by $0v = 0$.

Additivity: $0(v+w) = 0v + 0w$ for all $v,w \in V$.

Homogeneity: $0(av) = a(0v)$ for all $a \in \mathbb{F}$ and all $v \in V$.

Therefore $T$ is linear.

Is this verification correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.  Why don't you try a slightly more interesting operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good, but for such an elementary question, you shouldn't be using $ 0 $ to denote the function that maps everything to $ 0 $. Because if you do, it becomes very hard to distinguish mentally between 'scalar multiplication by 0' and 'applying the function 0'.

In your case $ 0(v+w) = 0v + 0w $ is not an argument: it is a restatement of what you have to prove. If you call the function $N$ that maps everything to $0$, that becomes clear; it would then be $N(v+w) = N(v) + N(w)$.

Now, a proof is still going to be trivial, but it will look like $N(v + w) = 0 = 0 + 0 = N(v) + N(w) $ and  $N(av) = 0 = a 0 = a N(v)$.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Thanks for point this out.

Comment: Can I start a bounty to give you slightly more bounty? I am so glad someone pointed this out.

Comment: Don't worry - I'm just glad to have helped.